# Bootstrap Datepicker mobile conflict

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using [Bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which works fine in chrome but when I try and select a date on an iPhone the standard [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) displays and not the Bootstrap Datepicker. How can I show the bootstrap datepicker on an iphone? 
I read in the docs about using noConflict (code below) but I'm not sure how to implement it into my code.

```
$('#start').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    todayBtn: true,
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    toggleActive: true
 });
```

How to use noConflict()?

```
var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict(); // return $.fn.datepicker to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;                 // give $().bootstrapDP the bootstrap-datepicker functionality
```

Comment: What is exactly your issue with the code? This example from the docs is used to "save" bootstrap's datepicker before it is eventually overriden by something else. You should put this code right after the bootstrap datepicker's script, and then use `$(selector).bootstrapDP();` instead of `$(selector).datepicker();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
 jquery ui
<input type="text" class="dp-jqueryui">
 <br>
 boostrap
 <input type="text" class="dp-bootstrap">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
 
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  
  $(function(){
   if (!$.fn.bootstrapDP && $.fn.datepicker && $.fn.datepicker.noConflict) {
    var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
    $.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;
  }
    $('.dp-jqueryui').datepicker();
    $('.dp-bootstrap').bootstrapDP();
   
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```